# Google Analytics quota dayshift

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm working on a solution where we need to request the Google Analytics API quite a lot. Now the issue is I want to allocate my requests because of the day quota limits. But right now it's quite unclear when Google makes it a new day and I have another 50.000 requests to make. From the developer console report I can get a detailed picture of the daily requests used.
Does anyone knows at what time of day and in which timezone the requests are reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request that Google Extend your 50,000 quota.  Note: I am not sure if they charge for this or not.   You can only do this though the old [Apis console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) for your app.  I have been unable to find this feature in the new [cloud developers console](https://console.developers.google.com).  (I have sent in a feature request on it)

On the right you will find a link to Request more.   But you need to make sure that you don't have to many errors returning from the API this will effect weather or not they will except your request to extend.

[image]

[Note: Daily quotas refresh at midnight PST.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas#discovery)

Comment: I got this far too. My issue was that the reported (excel) stated that my downloads was from the 2nd of march, and I'm hosting in europe, running the 3rd of march. It seems like around 9am I had the shift to the 3rd according to the report and a "reset" of the daily quota.

Comment: You do have the max-results set as high as you can right?  I have found hitting the 50k requests really hard. Especially when you consider that you must be querying on at least 5 different views (profiles) to achieve that number.  (Btw I suspect that it resets west cost US time. I have no prof of this but I know who I can ask.)

Comment: Got an answer: Daily quotas refresh at midnight PST.

Comment: Awesome, in this case I think recently could also be a matter of hours :)

Comment: As for the limit, I'm fetching some historic data. But I'll take a second look at the max-results, thanks for the hint. So far my Google Analytics extract skills are only a couple of weeks old :)